# Python appending random int in range to list, count number of occurences of numbers

Tags: python, random

So I have the following code:

```
import random
from collections import Counter
L = []
for x in range(0, 100):
    L.append([])
    for y in range(0, 6):
        L[x].append(random.randint(0, 45) + 1)
```

Now I need to be able to count the number of times each number appears in the list.
I tried counter and all kinds of other stuff, still get errors and I'm stuck.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are making sublists?

Comment: Because i'd like it to be in block of 6.
So basically it generates ints in blocks of 6, x amount of times. After which i want to be able to count the number of occurences of every number.

Comment: Please show your expected output then. You want a counter for each sublist?

Comment: I just want the amount of occurences.

I'm guessing the sublists aren't a good idea then?

Comment: Whether or not it's a good idea depends on what you actually want to achieve, that's why I'm asking for your expected output

Comment: 1: 10, 2 : 3, and so on. Kind of like seeing how many times certain numbers appear in a lottery, when the lottery is being done x amount of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to make use of the dictionary `.get()` method to increment values if they have been seen before, or start with a default count of 0.

```
my_count = {}
for lst in L:
    for item in lst:
        my_count[item] = my_count.get(item, 0) + 1
```

However, since you're already iterating in this way to create the list, you can do it all together:

```
import random

my_count = {}
L = []
for x in range(0, 100):
    L.append([])
    for y in range(0, 6):
        num = random.randint(0, 45) + 1
        L[x].append(num)
        my_count[num] = my_count.get(num, 0) + 1
```

Comment: It's not very efficient to append and empty sublist to `L` and then search for it by index 6 times in the for loop just to append it.

Comment: @DušanMaďar I really don't know what you're talking about. I'm not indexing anything

Comment: @DušanMaďar the OP is the one that set the loop up that way, I just put a counter in the loops. Both the dictionary search and the list indexing is O(1)

Comment: I meant `L[x].append(num)`.

Comment: @DušanMaďar ... that's their code. And it's still O(1), there is no search.

Answer (score 1):

You can store a per sublist `Counter` in a list and then sum all these counters.

I assume you want the count of each number across all sublists.

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce
import random


L = []
counters = []

for _ in range(0, 100):
    sublist = []

    for y in range(0, 6):
        sublist.append(random.randint(0, 45) + 1)

    counters.append(Counter(sublist))
    L.append(sublist)


def counter_reducer(accumulator, next_item):
    return accumulator + next_item


counts = reduce(counter_reducer, counters, Counter())
print(counts)  # Counter({23: 20, 46: 19, 12: 19, ...})
```

Comment: This works! Thanks, been stuck on this for days now (though it might have something to do with me trying to learn python ^.^ )

Comment: @MatthiasDeVos Happy to help. FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right  - You can create another list with the length of all your possible numbers, now every time that number appended you are adding 1 to the his corresponding index
, say:

```
count_list = [0] * 47
L = []
for x in range(0, 100):
L.append([])
for y in range(0, 6):
    L[x].append(random.randint(0, 45) + 1)
    count_list[L[x][y]] += 1
```

now, every index in the coubt_list represent a number and inside him the number of appears

Comment: Getting a TypeError when trying your code:
 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Comment: You're right, I forgot to add the y index of each sub-array. Edited

Answer (score 0):

You can add a List contain the same elements as L and count them using count 
try this :

```
L = []
e = []
for x in range(0, 10):
    L.append([])
    for y in range(0, 3):
        a = random.randint(0, 45) + 1
        L[x].append(a)
        e.append(a)
for z in e :
print (z,e.count(z))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) function from numpy:

```
import numpy as np 
import random
from collections import Counter
L = []
ll, lu = 0, 45 # set bounds for random samples
for x in range(0, 2):
    L.append([])
    for y in range(0, 3):
        L[x].append(random.randint(ll,lu) + 1)


bcen=np.linspace(ll, lu, lu+1) # centers
bed=np.linspace(ll-0.5, lu+0.5, lu+2) #edges
cnts, bed =np.histogram(L, bins=bed)

print('Random integers')
print(L)
print('Counts')
print(np.append(bcen.reshape(-1,1),cnts.reshape(-1,1), axis=1))
```

Note: I made your list smaller, just so that the print out is readable, but just adjust it as you wish.

Comment: Did you test this out...?

Comment: Actually, ok, it does, you decided to change the sample for some reason

Comment: I changed the list size just so that the print out is easy to read and verify :)